# Generate XSD from C# .net core classes with DataAnnotations defined

Tags: c#, xsd

I have some models defined in C# on the model I have added a bunch of DataAnnotations (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations), to specify things such as Max length, regular expressions, required etc...

I'd like to generate an XSD that will take into consideration all the DataAnnotation values I've specified, but cannot find a way. I know I could redefine the entire model structure in a .net 462 app and place XmlElement attributes on all the models, then use xsd.exe to generate the xsd, but that's not ideal.

Is there a way to generate the xsd with a .net core app and DataAnnotations defined?

Comment: did you get any answer to this?, got as far as the xsd.exe comlaining about DataAnnotation refernce.

Comment: Afraid not, in the end I switched to JSON, so it wasn't a problem

Comment: @Slicc did you found any tool?